# navigation.push not adding a new route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

`navigate` works fine however when I replace it with `push`, it stops working.

```
  <Text
          onPress={() => {
          //works  
          this.props.navigation.navigate("VideoPlayer", { id });
          // doesn't work
           this.props.navigation.push("VideoPlayer", { id });
          }}
          style={styles.text}
        >
          {title}
        </Text>
```

How can I get push to work so I can remount components?

I am using a `Drawer` with a new `stack` for each route so I can use `headers`:

```
const config = {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
        itemStyle: {
            flexDirection: "row-reverse"
        }
    },
    drawerWidth: 300,
    drawerPosition: "right"
};

const withHeader = (
    screen: Function,
    routeName: string,
    Header
): StackNavigator =>
    createStackNavigator(
        {
            [routeName]: {
                screen,
                navigationOptions: ({ routeName, props }) => ({
                    header: props => <Header {...props} />
                })
            }
        },
        {
            transparentCard: true
        }
    );

const routes = {
    Home: {
        screen: withHeader(HomeScreen, "Home", BasicHeader)
    },
    Links: {
        screen: withHeader(LinksScreen, "Links", DrawerHeader)
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: withHeader(SettingsScreen, "Settings", DrawerHeader)
    },
    VideoEpisodes: {
        screen: withHeader(VideoEpisodesScreen, "Video Episodes", DrawerHeader)
    },
    VideoPlayer: {
        screen: withHeader(VideoPlayerScreen, "Video Player", DrawerHeader)
    },
    TestYourself: {
        screen: withHeader(TestYourselfScreen, "Test Yourself", DrawerHeader)
    },
    MyResults: {
        screen: withHeader(MyResultsScreen, "My Results", DrawerHeader)
    },
    BookmarkedVideos: {
        screen: withHeader(
            BookmarkedVideosScreen,
            "Bookmarked Videos",
            DrawerHeader
        )
    },
    Search: {
        screen: withHeader(SearchScreen, "Search", DrawerHeader)
    },
    About: {
        screen: withHeader(AboutScreen, "About", DrawerHeader)
    }
};

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routes, config);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

.push() is a StackAction method, you have to use a stackNavigator in order to use it

Comment: How else would I be able to remount my page?